# how to add multiple rules for a pincode in table rates

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, table-rates, price-rules

I want to add multiple rules for a pincode . for eg:

```
if the 

Order Subtotal (and above) is 10,0000   then the Shipping Price will be 0
```

and

```
if the 

Order Subtotal is less than 1000 then the Shipping Price will be 100
```

for the

pincode `673302` , how can i apply these rules in table rates or how i apply

multiple rules ?

Now my table rate csv is this , is there any workarounds , can i add

cityname too in the table rates ,so that i can change shipping rate

according to cities ?
[image]

Comment: You could take a look at `Shoppingcart rules`. You can use exact input of the users address city as a rule filter. Apply the discount to sendcost only. These tables will limit you to zip codes / country code / subtotal combination

Comment: Did you solve? @Pista

Answer (score 2):

the zipcode field is a from to field. 
so this means you have to do
673302-673302

Be aware if you add a * zipcode blow that, this will be overwritten. 
so you need to declare other zipcodes.
671000-673301 for example.

hope this helps

Comment: so can i add 671000-673301 in the zip / postal code region ? can i add city names

Comment: No city names will not work. and indeed you can enter 671000-673301

Comment: unfortunately "IN * 673001-673602 100000 0"  lIke this not working

Comment: I guess its trimming the value from csv , when the exported the current csv it gives "673001-673" trimming last 3 digits